# Strange behaviors of finitely additive probabilities

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, probability-theory, self-learning

Watching a lecture on youtube I heard the lecturer stating that in general **finitely additive probabilities** behaves *strangely*. For example, it is possible that every open interval around a point $x$ has probability $1/2$, while $p(\{x\})=0$.

This lead me to various questions:

1. Is there somebody who can explain how do we get to this specific result?
2. What are other examples of strange behavior by finitely additive probabilities?
3. Why – in general – countably additive probabilities let us avoid these kind of *strange* situations?

As always, any feedback will be most welcome.
Thank you for your help and your time.

*[Just to underline a point, being self-taught, I do rely occasionally on youtube videos, but I am very selective about the provenience of the videos. In this case, the lecturer was a top theorist from a top university]*

Comment: To the moderators: I was thinking to add the soft-question tag, because this could be considered slightly generic (even if I did try to avoid this effect, trying to be as specific as possible). However, I think that using that tag would be misleading, being on the contrary a rather _mathematical_ question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With countable additivity, it is easy to prove continuity of measure from below and from above. That is, the measure of an increasing countable union is the limit of the measures of the finite unions. The same holds for decreasing intersections provided one of the sets has finite measure (which holds for probability of course). This would prevent your case, in that it would give $ P (\{ x \}) =1/2$.

Basically if you only assume finite additivity then you can't do limit processes of any sort.

Unfortunately, writing down an example of such an object on a "rich" $\sigma $-algebra like the Lebesgue measurable subsets of the reals is impossible, because their nonexistence is consistent with ZF.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do see now how the limiting process relates to case I described. Actually, I find a bit cryptic your last paragraph.

Comment: @Kolmin I admit, I did not say what "rich" means. Focusing just on the Lebesgue measurable subsets of the reals, with the axiom of choice there are finitely additive measures. Without it there may not be any finitely additive measures.

Answer (score 2):

The probability measure defined by the Kolmogorov axioms (which include countable additivity) are *set-continuous:* the probability of a limit is the limit of
the probabilities.  If one denies countable additivity and accepts only
finite additivity, then this set-continuity property is no longer applicable.

Consider the following notion from Calculus 101 (which is perhaps describable as
the study of properties of continuous functions). Suppose $f(x)$ is a function
that approaches a limit $L$ as $x \to a$. Then, it is *not* necessary that
$f(a)$ be *equal* to $L$; $f(a)$ can have any arbitrary value. But when 
$f(a)$
*does* equal $L$, we say that $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$. If $f(x)$ is
continuous at all $a \in (-\infty,\infty)$, we call it a continuous function. Similarly, 
countable additivity gives us set-continuity for all events in the
$\sigma$-algebra but finite additivity does not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thus, regarding your reference to the Kolmogorov's axioms, does it actually implies that finitely additive measures are _not_  in the Kolmogorov's framework?

Comment: Regarding your answer, finding it in line with the one given by Ian, I will accept his answer for fairness concerns, simply because he wrote it before. Again, thanks a lot.